# Looal Dynamo db insert validation exception error

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning to use dynamodb and am getting An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: One of the required keys was not given a value when trying to run my mock test to insert a value. I am trying to create a mock test. I am clearly missing something and don't understand. The code is largely based off of this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/). I removed some of the data being inserted for simplicity.

Test data:

```
{ 
    "email": "email@b.com"
}
```

Here is my table definition:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name Profile \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=email,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema AttributeName=email,KeyType=HASH  \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 \
    --table-class STANDARD \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

It exists in my local dynamo db instance

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Profile --endpoint-url=http://localhost:8000
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "email",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "Profile",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "email",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": "2022-11-20T00:39:06.505000-06:00",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1969-12-31T18:00:00-06:00",
            "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1969-12-31T18:00:00-06:00",
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/Profile"
```

This is my .env file

```
AWS_REGION=us-fake-1
DDB_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8000
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=fake
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=fake
API_PROFILESAPI_PROFILETABLE_NAME=ProfileTable
```

This is my unit test

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import re
import logging
import unittest

from moto import mock_dynamodb
from http import HTTPStatus
# Seperate inserts are needed to support uniqueness in items other than pk
# use tranaction for rollback

@mock_dynamodb
class TestDatabaseFunctions(unittest.TestCase):


    def validateProfile(self, event):
        profile_data = {}
        for x in self.re_dict.keys():
            self.logging.info(f"Validating {x}")
            if not re.search(self.re_dict[x], str(event[x])):
                print(f"{event[x]} does not match {self.re_dict[x]}")
                self.logging.debug(f"{event[x]} does not match {self.re_dict[x]}")
                return False, profile_data
            else:
                profile_data[x] = event[x]
        return True, profile_data

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.logging = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.re_dict = {
            "email": "(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)",

        }
        self.testHandler()
    
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        return super().tearDown()
    
    def insertProfile(self, profile):
        message = f"Profile was not created"
        dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
        response = dynamodb.transact_write_items(
                TransactItems=[
                    {
                        'Put': {
                            'TableName': 'Profile',
                            'Item':{
                                'email' : {
                                    'S': profile['email'],   
                                }

                            },
                            'ConditionExpression':'attribute_not_exists(pk)'
                        },
                        'Put': {
                            'TableName': 'Profile',
                            'Item':{
                                'pk': {
                                    'S': f"username#{profile['username']}"
                                }
                            },
                            'ConditionExpression':'attribute_not_exists(pk)'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            )
            
        return {
            "status_code": response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'],
            "message": message
        }

    def testHandler(self) -> None:
        response = {
            "status_code": HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            "message": "Creation was not successful."
        }
        with open("../event.json", 'r') as f:
            event = json.loads(f.read())
            self.logging.info(event)

        is_valid, profileData = self.validateProfile(event)
        self.assertEqual(True, is_valid) 
        response = self.insertProfile(profileData)
        self.assertEqual(HTTPStatus.OK, response) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every one of the items you try to `Put` must have its key attributes - in your case that is the "email" attribute - set. But it seems one of your calls used the name "pk" instead of "email", I guess a copy-pasto.

You also mention "pk" in the ConditionExpression - that's a typo too?

Comment: I decided to use the email instead of an id as primary key. I was under the impression that pk was required to designate the primary key as you would in a sql db

Comment: The schema of the table, which you define with create-table, determines the primary key attribute names. In your case you called this attribute "email". So from thereon, you need to use the attribute "email" to set an item's key. Not the meaningless string "pk".